# Application losing Printer within Terminal Services for remote users

Tags: terminal-server, windows-terminal-services, printing, printer

Question:  What I need to do is have a permanent link to a printer, normally only accessible through Terminal Services (Printer Redirect), to allow Sage Line 50 layouts to see that printer persistently, even after users have disconnected and reconnected to the Terminal Services session?

Although the printer is accessible each time a user connects to the Sage Server via Terminal Services, it is given a different session number and therefore the Sage Layout sees it as a different printer.

History behind question:

Users using Terminal Services connecting to a Sage Server on a different site
Using Sage Line 50 v 15 on that Server
Users want to print invoices (sage layouts) locally
Sage Server cannot see the users local printers, to get around this user uses the Print redirect features of Terminal Services

The individual reports can be edited to point to a specific printer by default.  This means the user just has to select an invoice and click print, then select the layout/report wanted and it auto prints that invoice to the default printer specified.

The problem occurs because the layouts are edited to point to the users local printer "Ricoh 1018d (session#)", note the "(session#)" as this is the users local printer being redirected through the terminal services session.

Users are able to print using the sage layouts once the default printer is setup within the layout and saved, but as soon as the users disconnects from the Terminal Services session and then reconnect in the morning go to print, it has lost the connection to that printer.

I understand why its failed, because that the printer is on a per session basis and the layout would not be able to hold on to the connection from a previous session.

Thanks in advance for any assistance...

Answer (score 1):

Some assuming, if these are local users and are just logging into this server or are logging in remotely via VPN for this one application, wouldn't it be easier to just install the Ricoh locally on the Server pointing to the IP

Then just tell users to print to that printer, as it's IP based they wont have to play with settings or session ID's

HTH

Comment: Server is in a remote site, as this is a multi site company, Users connect to the server using an external IP and port forwarding.  Otherwise this would have been a much easier solution.

Comment: If this is a multi site company, can you set up a VPN, do your Routers support it?

Comment: I think a site-site vpn will be the best way to go.  Whether it is an entire site or just individuals, we can decide at a later date.  Thanks for your help..